# How to sign out of Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have transitioned from Azure AD B2B to Azure AD B2C, and my previous logout process was as follows:

```
public IActionResult SignOut()
{
    var callbackUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Inicio", values: null, protocol: Request.Scheme);
    return SignOut(
        new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = callbackUrl },
        CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}
```

However, this method no longer works.

I've attempted the following logout approach:

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult SignOut()
{
    return RedirectToAction("Logout");
}

[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
{
    HttpContext.Session.Clear();
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(AzureADB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(AzureADB2CDefaults.CookieScheme);
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(AzureADB2CDefaults.OpenIdScheme);
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    var config = InfoUserAD.ReadConfig();

    string tenantId = config.Domain.Split('.')[0];
    string policy = config.Resource;
    string clientId = config.ClientId;
    string redirectUrl = "http://localhost:5001/"; // URL to redirect to after logout
    string logoutUrl = $"https://{tenantId}.b2clogin.com/{tenantId}.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/logout?p={policy}";

    string encodedRedirectUrl = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(redirectUrl);
    string logoutFullUrl = $"{logoutUrl}&post_logout_redirect_uri={encodedRedirectUrl}";

    return Redirect(logoutFullUrl); 
}
```

Unfortunately, I am encountering the same issue. While it appears that the session is closing successfully, when attempting to log in again, it automatically logs in with the previous session's data.

Uri Redirect
[UriRedirect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1myWk.png)

Comment: You are clearing the session but cookies are not cleared.In `LogOut()` method add `await HttpContext.ClearCookiesAsync();` after `HttpContext.Session.Clear();`

Comment: Since my application doesn't allow me to use await HttpContext.ClearCookiesAsync();, I opted to use: foreach (var cookie in Request.Cookies.Keys)
{
    Response.Cookies.Delete(cookie);
}
However, the same error still persists. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Hello, I found that with this URL $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri={redirectUrl}" I can log out of the account, but the redirection to the redirectUrl doesn't work. Do you know of any solution for this error?

Comment: Please share redirect URI screenshot.